# omniauth-facebook: How to save an avatar with Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook, rails-activestorage

I use `omniauth-facebook` gem to authenticate users. However I don't know how to store an avatar to Active Storage.
Can anybody advise me on that?

I've tried those two ways. But none of them works.

```
user.avatar = auth.info.image
```

neither

```
downloaded_image = open(auth.info.image)
user.avatar.attach(io: downloaded_image, filename: 'avatar.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg')
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you say _"none of them works"_, what do you mean? Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

`auth.info.image` return a string which is a url to the avatar. If you just want to display the avatar, I suggest just use a string field and store the url.

If you really want to download the image and save it, try the following code:

```
# in order to use the open() method with urls
require 'open-uri'

# open the link
downloaded_image = open(auth.info.image)

# upload via ActiveStorage
# be careful here! the type may be png or other type!
user.avatar.attach(io: downloaded_image, filename: 'avatar.jpg', content_type: downloaded_image.content_type)
```